# Ubuntu run Puma and Sidekiq in background as Daemonized processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-5, ubuntu-14.04

Two years ago I was running the following command:

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b unix:/home/user/site/shared/tmp/sockets/user-puma.sock -d
bundle exec sidekiq -d
```

But now, after some Ubuntu updates, the `-d` flag is deprecated and I can't start the Puma and Sidekiq processes to run in background.

I also tried running:

```
bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -b unix:/home/user/site/shared/tmp/sockets/user-puma.sock &
bundle exec sidekiq &
```

This works only while I'm logged on the SSH, when I close the SSH connection, all processes opened with `&` are closed.

How can I run Puma, Sidekiq and other processes in background as Daemons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me is setting up my own systemd service for sidekiq

A well-documented example file is in [the sidekiq github repository](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/main/examples/systemd/sidekiq.service)

Along with this, I'd also recommend using [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) to watch background processes... [here's a recipe from Lugo Labs](https://mmonit.com/monit/) that I loosely base my deploys off of

Comment: And the sidekiq.service should be created in:  /etc/systemd/system/sidekiq.service ? Same for puma? I discovered this config for Puma: https://gist.github.com/arteezy/5d53d99f6ee617fae1f0db0576fdd418#gistcomment-3113201

Comment: Yes. You can name the services whatever you want. And don't forget to run `sudo systemctl enable sidekiq` (and likewise for puma service) to get those services to start automatically on boot.